# Auto complete tool for multi-dimensional assosiative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, autocomplete

I'm looking for plugin. Below I've got my code in php. It is an multi-dimensional array as you see.

```
$multi = array(
            '1' => array(
                    'who' => array(
                            'name' => 'John',
                            'surname' => 'Bar',
                            'date' => array(
                                    'day' => 1,
                                    'month' => 2,
                                    'year' => 1990
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            '2' => array(
                    'who' => array(
                            'name' => 'Joanna',
                            'surname' => 'Lu',
                            'date' => array(
                                    'day' => 11,
                                    'month' => 12,
                                    'year' => 1992
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
            '3' => array(
                    'who' => array(
                            'name' => 'Mark',
                            'surname' => 'Bock',
                            'date' => array(
                                    'day' => 5,
                                    'month' => 2,
                                    'year' => 1980
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
        );
```

Plugin should auto complete code or give some proposals when I'm accessing in deep like:

```
$year = $multi['1']['who']['date']['year'];
```

I mean that I may have no idea what is in $multi['1'] and I need code assistance. Does such tool exist? Plugin should work in eclipse or netbeans as I use it in casual working day.

Answer (score 1):

[PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) does this, as long as the array isn't dynamically generated. That can only computed at run-time.

Comment: Certainly you're right but I need something open source for eclipse or netbeans.

Comment: @MarekBar: why open source? because you want it to be free? I think PhpStorm is worth the price tag, but that's just my opinion.